# I keep getting this request for a Yahoo Messenger Buddy on empathy same person every time I log in?

Tags: empathy

I am not sure this belongs here, if not tell me and I will delete this question, but I was wondering could this be a bug with Yahoo not getting the denial from empathy?

Comment: Please file a bug report in Launchpad regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the same problem. Please file a bug in empathy by running this command in a terminal:

> ubuntu-bug empathy